# magento fatal - call to member getquote in checkout page

Tags: magento

proceed to checkout button displaying 2 times in cart page

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getQuote() on a non-object in /home/apd16/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php on line 195
```

I have no idea why its happened suddenly

Comment: Are you resolve this error ?

Comment: @RudolfPipopulo the theme we are using have that feature of displaying `proceed to checkout`  butto 2 times in cart page....

Comment: In my case the error caused Amasty customer attribute - after uninstall - problem solved